Azure Pipeline timeout with testcontainers
I have a similar issue as this: Testcontainers: Azure pipeline test stage reach timeout of 1hour
I would have commented there but I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation.
It's the same case, except I'm using NUnit instead of xUnit. Testcontainers MSSQL database should start in a base fixture which is reused. Locally everything works fine.
Also, I tried to create a console app which will run the same container, connect to it and try executing SELECT 1. Locally it works, on Azure pipeline it gets stuck. I added logs from container and also docker logs from container.
From testcontainers, it just spams:
Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container 3e9c900b903c
From docker logs, I get following:
...
2024-07-26 13:05:18.95 spid50s     Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 952 to version 953.

2024-07-26 13:05:18.96 spid50s     Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 953 to version 954.

2024-07-26 13:05:18.97 spid50s     Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 954 to version 955.

2024-07-26 13:05:18.98 spid50s     Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 955 to version 956.

2024-07-26 13:05:19.01 spid50s     Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 956 to version 957.

2024-07-26 13:05:19.05 spid13s     Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2024-07-26 13:05:19.12 spid27s     The default language (LCID 0) has been set for engine and full-text services.

2024-07-26 13:05:19.20 spid27s     The tempdb database has 2 data file(s).

2024-07-26 13:10:16.69 spid62      XE session 'telemetry_xevents' started.

2024-07-26 13:10:44.25 spid62      Attempting to load library 'xplog70.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2024-07-26 13:10:44.29 spid62      Using 'xplog70.dll' version '2022.160.4135' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_msver'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.


After that, no more messages come in from dockers logs, and from testcontainers it just keeps spamming the same message.
Container is created like this:
new MsSqlBuilder()
            .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
            .WithCleanUp(true)
            .WithPortBinding(1431)
            .WithPassword("Password123!")
            .WithLogger(new ContainerLogger())
            .Build();


If anyone has any idea, I can't see what the issue would be since locally everything works without any issues. I was checking memory usage with diagnostic data, no issues. I also tried disabling parallelization, no help.


Is there any error or message in the debug log of your pipeline. 2. You said it worked on your local machine. You can set up a self-hosted agent on that machine. Then run your pipeline using this self-hosted agent and check what's the result.


Nothing, last message is “One test found…” and then it hangs until it times out. I can try setting up self hosted agent on my PC, but I’m not sure if that will help much. When running locally, even through command line, I see no issues or logs.

If you are building the same project in the pipeline, the pipeline and your local environment may be different. If you use the self-hosted agent, pipeline works fine, check the environment between your local and MS-hosted agent.

I had the same issue on 24 July on an Azure DevOps pipeline, took me a while to figure out. Everything worked locally without issues, but the pipeline didn't advance beyond the container readiness check.
It turned out that the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest image was updated on 23 July 2024 to use the version with tag 2022-CU14-ubuntu-22.04. I fixed the issue by not using the latest image, but the 2022-CU13-ubuntu-22.04 version instead. I am unsure if the issue lies with the image itself, the way testcontainers uses it, or with the build agent, I didn't investigate too much after finding a fix.
So, in the testcontainer setup, I changed .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest") to .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-CU13-ubuntu-22.04"), and now the pipeline is working again. If latest is again updated to a new version, I will try that again, but for now, the pipeline works at least.

Thank you! I didn't even consider the image being a problem.
